# Chat active cable rails (WebSocket) - борьба с перезагрузками

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Файл app/channels/conversation_channel.rb:

```
class ConversationChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
  def subscribed
    stream_from "conversations-#{current_profile.id}"
  end

  def unsubscribed
    stop_all_streams
  end

  def speak(data)
    message_params = data['message'].each_with_object({}) do |el, hash|
      hash[el.values.first] = el.values.last
    end

    Message.create(message_params)
  end
end
```

`stream_from "conversations-#{current_profile.id}"` - подписывается на беседу и на свой поток

Файл job/message_broadcast.rb:

```
class MessageBroadcastJob < ApplicationJob
  queue_as :default

  def perform(message)
    sender = message.profile
    recipient = message.conversation.opposed_profile(sender)

    broadcast_to_sender(sender, message)
    broadcast_to_recipient(recipient, message)
  end

  private

  def broadcast_to_sender(profile, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{profile.id}",
      message: render_message(message, profile),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id)
  end

  def broadcast_to_recipient(profile, message)
    ActionCable.server.broadcast(
      "conversations-#{profile.id}",
      window: render_window(message.conversation, profile),
      message: render_message(message, profile),
      conversation_id: message.conversation_id)
  end

  def render_message(message, profile)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'messages/message',
      locals: { message: message, profile: profile })
  end

  def render_window(conversation, profile)
    ApplicationController.render(
      partial: 'conversations/conversation',
      locals: { conversation: conversation, profile: profile })
  end
end
```

Здесь же происходит вещание. Но приходится перезагружать страницу, чтобы отобразилось сообщение.

При отправке сообщения у пользователя, который отправлял сообщение показывается, у другого нет. Это видно в консоле:

```
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-
eb5eac79e41b]   Rendered messages/_message.html.erb (1.1ms)
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b] 
[ActionCable] Broadcasting to conversations-1: {:message=>"<li>\n  <div class=\"row\">\n    <div class=\"message-sent\">\n      201\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</li>\n", :conversation_id=>1}
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b]   Rendered conversations/_conversation.html.erb (15.5ms)
[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b] Error performing MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: 42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b) from Async(default) in 57.15ms: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial application/_conversation_content with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff, :svg, :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json, :pdf, :zip, :gzip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
* "/home/steepbeaver/Prespy/app/views"
* "/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/devise-4.3.0/app/views"):
ConversationChannel transmitting {"message"=>"<li>\n  <div class=\"row\">\n    <div class=\"message-sent\">\n      201\n    </div>\n  </div>\n</li>\n", "conversation_id"=>1} (via streamed from conversations-1)
```

Заранее спасибо за ваши комментарии и ответы. В любой момент готов дополнить информацию!

Comment: Так исправьте ту ошибку, что процитировали, для начала.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разгадка крылась здесь:

`[ActiveJob] [MessageBroadcastJob] [42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b] Error performing MessageBroadcastJob (Job ID: 42a34e05-37c3-46d3-bace-eb5eac79e41b) from Async(default) in 57.15ms: ActionView::Template::Error (Missing partial application/_conversation_content with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, ........]}`

В папке **`app/views`** нужно было создать папку **`application`** c файлом **`_conversation_content`**

Comment: Ну вот. Можете же, когда хотите :)